# Want to add a canvas in BorderPane, how?

Tags: javafx-8

So im new to javaFX and want to make a borderpane with some buttons on the left and a canvas to draw lines with mouse in center.. on line 49 and 55 i get an error saying "cannot find symbol, variable scene".. why is that?

Please ignore my buttons, they are just there for show. Any other mistakes or pointers I would love aswell!

```
package simplepaint;

import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;

public class SimplePaint extends Application { 

    Button but0, but1, but2, but3, but4, but5, but6;



   @Override 
   public void start(Stage primaryStage) { 
       primaryStage.setTitle("Simple paint");

       //Creates all buttons
       but0 = new Button("0"); //Create button - Line
       but1 = new Button("1"); //Create button - rectangle
       but2 = new Button("2"); //Create button - circle
       but3 = new Button("3"); //Create button - move object backwards
       but4 = new Button("4"); //Create button - Move object foreward
       but5 = new Button("5"); //Create button - Move object backwards(1 spot)
       but6 = new Button("6"); //Create button - Move object foreward (1 spot)

       //Gives all buttons functions
       but0.setOnAction(e -> System.out.println("Bro 0!"));
       but1.setOnAction(e -> System.out.println("Bro 1!"));
       but2.setOnAction(e -> System.out.println("Bro 2!"));
       but3.setOnAction(e -> System.out.println("Bro 3!"));
       but4.setOnAction(e -> System.out.println("Bro 4!"));
       but5.setOnAction(e -> System.out.println("Bro 5!"));
       but6.setOnAction(e -> System.out.println("Bro 6!"));

       Canvas canvas = new Canvas(750,450); //Making draw window
       GraphicsContext gc;
       gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
       gc.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
       gc.setLineWidth(1);

      /*Line 49*/ scene.setOnMousePressed (e -> {
           gc.beginPath();
           gc.lineTo(e.getSceneX(), e.getSceneY());
           gc.stroke();
       });

      /*Line 55*/ scene.setOnMouseDragged (e -> {
           gc.lineTo(e.getSceneX(), e.getSceneY());
           gc.stroke();
       });

       VBox buttons = new VBox(3);
       buttons.setPadding(new Insets(50, 10, 10, 10));
       buttons.getChildren().addAll(but0, but1, but2, but3, but4, but5, but6); //Adds all the buttons on VBox

       BorderPane bp = new BorderPane();
       bp.setLeft(buttons); //Placing buttons on left
       bp.setCenter(canvas); //Placing draw box in center

       Scene scene = new Scene(bp, 800, 500);
       primaryStage.setScene(scene);
       primaryStage.show();

   }  public static void main(String[] args) {
       Application.launch(args);
   }
}
```

Comment: You're declaring the variable in line ***68***. Java requires local variables to be declared before they are used...

Comment: Makes sence! Thanks @fabian